NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'jobs_plumbers.job_id' could not find table 'jobs' with which to generate a foreign key to
I am creating a many to many relationships for base model which involves plumbers and jobs.
a plumber can apply to many jobs and many jobs can be done by one plumber, many plumbers can apply to one job and also a plumber can apply to the next job even if he gets assigned or not.
i defined the plumbers table class and the jobs table class and created a jobs-plumber table with foreignkeys to both jobs.id and plumbers.id. and a relationship on both plumbers and clients with secondary= jobs-plumber and backref to jobs and plumbers been the table names.
but i still get this error
NoReferencedTableError
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'jobs_plumbers.job_id' could not find table 'jobs' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'.

This is my code and all exists inside one file
The association table between jobs and plumbers
`jobs_plumbers = Table('jobs_plumbers', metadata,
     Column('job_id', Integer, ForeignKey('jobs.id'), primary_key=True),                  
    Column('plumber_id', Integer, ForeignKey('plumbers.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Plumber(BaseUser):
    """ Plumber models from Baseuser """
    __tablename__ = 'plumbers'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('base_user.id'), primary_key=True)
    # bio = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    # service_areas = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    # Establishing a many to many relationship between plumbers and jobs
    jobs = relationship('Job', secondary=jobs_plumbers, backref='plumbers')

# Relationship between plumbers and clients messages and ranking
message = relationship('Message', backref='plumber_message')
rank = relationship('Rank', backref='plumber_rank')

class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    
     # Relationship between jobs and plumbers
    plumbers = relationship('Plumber', secondary=jobs_plumbers, backref='jobs')

job_title = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
job_description = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
completed = Column(Boolean, default=False)
content = Column(String(1000), nullable=False)
date_posted = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
location = Column(String(100), nullable=False)  


# Relationship between jobs and plumber mesaages if they even exit
# message = relationship('Message', backref='job_message')
rank = relationship('Rank', backref='job_rank')

if i am to move the Job class to be above the Plumber class, the error will change to this
NoReferencedTableError
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'jobs_plumbers.plumber_id' could not find table 'plumbers' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

can someone look into this for me
Thanks
I have tried moving it to different positions on the file but yet it is the same.
I read the documentation and tried that out too but can't get anything to resolve this.
